# Node.js Dwolla passportjs error "failed to fetch user profile"

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, dwolla

"failed to fetch user profile" error.

I pasted the code into my application and receive the error mentioned above. I'm somewhat familiar with passportjs as I have used it successfully in the past but cannot debug this issue. I am being redirected to Dwolla to authenticate and returned to the callback method which prompts the error.

Link to the example code provided by Dwolla which I've copied and pasted.
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-dwolla/blob/master/examples/login/app.js

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the `user` endpoint for this strategy. The original uses:

`https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/accountapi/accountinformation`

I changed it to:

`https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/users/`

The updated strategy is here:

https://github.com/auth0/passport-dwolla